# Restart program in Python

Tags: python

Very new to python, building a simple game that asks users if they would like to play again once the game is finished. Initially the code below worked exactly as it should have and now it doesn't. Please help folks, very confused over here!

```
def again(users):
    play_again = input("Would you like to play again? (yes or no): ")
    aa = ['yes', 'no']  # acceptable answers
    while is_entry_invalid(aa, play_again):
        play_again = input("Would you like to play again? (yes or no): ")
    if play_again == 'yes':
        os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)  # nothing happens, program ends
    else:
        print('\nThank you for playing, ' + users[0] + ' and ' + users[1])
        exit()
```

Comment: Don't restart the program. Reset the variables/game state instead.

Comment: It'll be much easier with proper encapsulation: `while play_again: game = Game() ...`

Comment: I am more concerned with the fact that this exact code worked just as I hoped it would and now it doesn't. Should I not get any clarity I will go that route, thanks!

Comment: Would help anyone looking to answer this question if you let people know what error you're getting

Comment: getting no error, the program just ends

Comment: this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exit-commands-quit-exit-sys-exit-and-os-_exit/ should help you understand why

Comment: I don't see a problem with `execl` itself (unless sys.executable or sys.argv have been overwritten). You could add a print just before execl and first thing in the the program itself to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
play_again = input("Would you like to play again? (yes or no): ")
if play_again == 'yes':
    file = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    os.execl(sys.executable, os.path.abspath(file), *sys.argv)
```

This works ... I have a feeling your issue is that you are hitting 'Run Module' in the IDE environment and not just running the program as you would by clicking an icon on the desktop, for instance ...

Comment: is_entry_invalid returns False if the user entered 'yes' or 'no'. If it returns True, the user is stuck in the while loop until it inputs a proper answer. Otherwise it evaluates the answer and acts accordingly via if/else statement

Comment: try this: os.execl(sys.executable, os.path.abspath(__file__), *sys.argv) ...

Comment: is "file" the right path to where the program is located?

Comment: I believe so, I used 'file = os.path.abspath(__file__)'